# MYSQL - searching strings within a select

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to search a field in the database and see if the "changed from" and "to" values are different(the values are stored within a string in a single field).

Here is an example of what the string in the field looks like

```
Instance Person(34) modified by 1.
Field phone_number changed from "123" to "123".
Current field values are:
    first_name => "alex"
    last_name => "Handley"
```

In this example they are the same so would not be returned.

is it possible to do this ?

Alex

Comment: This data should be stored in separate fields in the database, so that you can write easier queries. eg. `WHERE changed_From <> changed_to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a job for a regular expression, not a database query.

You could do it with a stored procedure which makes a query, chops up the result, and compares the two parts.  But, again, this type of logic belongs at the application layer - either beforehand, storing the parts of the string you'll need to compare separately, or afterwards, extracting the useful info from the single database column.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has pretty nice [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) support. (It's also fast; I've found that REGEXP is often faster than LIKE).

I don't believe that it has back reference support, so it would be difficult to compare in a single query. You might be able to do it with a clever join or a stored procedure.